# Continuity and uniform continuity on a collection of sets, but not on the union of the sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$.

Let $X=\cup_{i=1}^n X_i.$

a.) Show that $f$ need not be continuous on $X$.

b.) Show that $f$ need not be uniformly continuous on $X.$

This task seems daunting, but let me know what you think. I'm struggling.

---

For a.), I could imagine constructing a union of disjoint open intervals and make the function undefined at each endpoint.

Here's what I mean:

Let $X=(0,a)\cup(a,b)\cup(b,c)\cup...\cup(y,z)$.

Let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)...(x-y)(x-z)}$

Now, for any $x \neq a,b,c,...,y,z,  f(x)$ is continuous

and for any $x=a,b,c,...,y,z, f(x)$ is undefined

But do note that for any $X_i, f(x)$ is continuous on the $X_i$ interval

---

For b.), I'm not sure where to start. In many cases, uniform continuity deals with vertical asymptotes so it's hard to imagine a union of sets that don't have vertical asymptotes, but one of their individual sets does.

Comment: The points $a,b,\ldots,z$ aren’t in $X$, so they don’t affect the continuity of $f$ at all.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What if I changed $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ instead to $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$? Then, it would be discontinuous on $X$

Comment: $\Bbb R$ isn’t the union of the intervals $(a,b),\ldots,(y,z)$: you’d have to change the sets $X_i$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott in what manner?

Comment: If you want the domain of $f$ to be $\Bbb R$, you have to have sets $X_i$ whose union is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Okay. I see. So are my $X_i$'s as I've defined them going to help me at all or is there a better designation of $X_i$'s?

Comment: I suspect not, but I’ve not actually thought about the problem: I just noticed that what you’d done didn’t work.